# All UI element (Buttons, EditText, etc.) has no styling at all (android)

Tags: android

hi i'm using eclipse and i just started creating a new project and I've found that all User interface element that i add has no style at all ([image](http://i60.tinypic.com/1o86z6.png)). i think it has something to do with updating the SDK (i don't know) because before that it was working just fine. My question is how to bring it back to normal. i don't want to create custom styles and i also don't want that plain styles, i want to have the normal android style. old styles like ([image](http://i60.tinypic.com/333zeye.jpg)) (not talking about background color. i'm talking about highlighting stuff being focused on etc.)

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dailygoallist"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: It has styles... What do you call "normal"? What "updating the SDK" thing you did? What "styles" did you had before?

Comment: show style.xml and AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: That's the Material style from Lollipop isn't it? In any case, you should shift to using Android Studio rather than Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it solution is pretty simple just change

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

in every style.xml to `parent="AppBaseTheme"` 
thanks for your help guys (Y)